# Jquery load content then refresh every 2 second

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am having trouble solving this, i'm trying to load a page which process a variable given by an input form then show the content based on the input, this worked fine, but i am also trying to refresh and update that input every 2 seconds

Below are my codes

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        function getData(){
        $("#dateslot").change(function(){
        var inputField= $('#dateslot').val();
        $("#timeslot").load('burgerorder_check.php?dateselect='+inputField);
        });
        setTimeout(getData,1000);
        };
        getData();

});
</script>
```

I'm trying to create a function that if someone else picked that, you won't be able to, which i successfully coded but not for the refresh part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the methods and variables in the wrong order. You should probably set a variable outside the getData scope that can change at anytime, then just use that variable when fetching data.

Also, use `setInterval` if you want to repeat the function. `setTimeout` is simply a delay.

```
var val; // the select value is stored here

$("#dateslot").change(function(){
    val = $(this).val(); // change the value
}
setInterval(getData,1000);
getData();
function getData(){
    if ( val ) {
        $("#timeslot").load('burgerorder_check.php?dateselect='+val);
    }
}
```